# Assets inside component folder in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic (v2) component, and I want to put an image of the component (that image is a default image for the compnent) in its folder so I can easily move the component in other project by cut and paste the folder.
I have tried in .scss file the following code:

```
background: url('./file.jpg') no-repeat;
```

but it doesn't work. What path I must write?

Answer (score 0):

it would be clear if you put your whole scss code here, assuming you named a class now inside perfrom this

```
 .some-css{
....other css
background-image: url(assets/img/file.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: I wanted to say that I have background-image: url(assets/img/file.jpg); in a class in my scss file but it doesn't work in ionic 2. It works in angular (I have changed the title form angular to ionic)